# leaflet marker click and doubleclick not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, leaflet

I have used awesome merker javascript with leaflet and added click and double click event

```
var Lmarker = L.marker([Stations[i].Y, Stations[i].X], {
            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                icon: 'circle',
                prefix: 'fa',
                iconColor: 'red',
                markerSize: '15px'
            })

Lmarker.on('click', onMarkerMouseClick);

 Lmarker.on('dblclick', onMapMarkerDoubleClick);
```

double click event is not working in firefox. Please help if anyone has used both event.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it on Firefox 31.3.0 ESR and it worked for me.

Did you try

```
Lmarker.on('dblclick', function(){ console.log('dblclick') });
Lmarker.on('click', function(){ console.log('click') });
```

This is how I checked it.

I noticed something strange: if you listen to click AND dblclick event, click event will also be called (twice) on double click.